# I'm having issues stopping Apache from rewriting URLs, even after a restart

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

All I want to do is be able to see a PHP file from the root without it going through the rewrites (thus our custom CMS).

Here's what I've done:

1. In my httpd.conf, I've commented out the call to load the mod_rewrite module.
2. Next, I've removed the .htaccess file from the root as it had the rewrite rules in it.
3. I've rebooted the server.
4. I've searched through phpinfo() and there are no "rewrite" strings to be found

The problem is that the server still rewrites and the request passes through our CMS.

I'm using XAMP (PHP 3.3.1, Apache 2.2.14)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave it to the details... I was trying to access my_file.php on the root. However, the filename was actually my-file.php (dash vs underscore).

The page I was getting was a 404, which went through the CMS. When I access the proper file, the one with the dash, I get what I'm supposed to.

I appologize for the waste of time :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe cache problem in your browser? because a similar thing happened to me and deleting the cache solved it.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and emptied my browsing data (all except cookies) and restarted the browser. Didn't help. I even tried in IE6, didn't work there either. Thanks for the help.